# PostgreSQL: how to find id's with max money in a weekly table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table holding virtual money for weekly tournaments:

```
# select * from pref_money limit 5;
       id       | money |   yw
----------------+-------+---------
 OK32378280203  |   -27 | 2010-44
 OK274037315447 |   -56 | 2010-44
 OK19644992852  |     8 | 2010-44
 OK21807961329  |   114 | 2010-44
 FB1845091917   |   774 | 2010-44
(5 rows)
```

In my PHP script listing users, I need to know who has been a weekly winner, so that I can show medals near their names. So I'm trying this SQL statement:

```
# find the weekly winners
$sth = $db->prepare('select id from pref_money 
    where money in 
    (select max(money) from pref_money group by yw)');

$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        @$medals[$row['id']]++;
```

This mostly works, but sometimes I get **false positives**, when a user happens to have the same amount of money in some week (but not max there) as the winner in another week.

Does anybody have an idea how to change the SQL statement, so that really only winner ids are being selected?

When I try the following, I get an error:

```
# select id, max(money) from pref_money group by yw;
ERROR:  column "pref_money.id" must appear in the 
  GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Thank you!
Alex

UPDATE: PostgreSQL 8.4.5 / CentOS and there can be ties :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version PostgreSQL? This is easy with windowing functions introduced in 8.4:

```
select id, yw from (
    select id,
           yw,
           row_number() over(partition by yw order by money desc) as ranking
    from pref_money
) x
where x.ranking = 1
```

This will just about do in older versions:

```
select id, yw
from pref_money
     join (select yw, max(money) max_money
           from pref_money
           group by yw) max_money
          on pref_money.yw = max_money.yw and pref_money.money = max_money.max_money
```

But observe that weeks where two users tie for the maximum money will be shown twice in the output. If that's actually what you want, you can do with with the windowing functions too, using `rank()` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: Thanks, but the 2nd code doesn't really work - displays all rows from pref_money table

Comment: oops... trying to neaten it up broke the join condition.

Comment: Thank you this works too (once you prepend select pref_money.id, pref_money.yw from .....)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming PostgreSQL 8.4+, and no one ties for the winner position in a given week -- this will list the weekly winners:

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT t.id,
         t.yw,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.yw
                               ORDER BY t.money DESC) AS rank
    FROM PREF_MONEY t)
SELECT s.id
  FROM sample s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

If there can be ties, use:

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT t.id,
         t.yw,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.yw
                               ORDER BY t.money DESC) AS rank
    FROM PREF_MONEY t)
SELECT s.id
  FROM sample s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

I included the `yw` column, in case you want/need to filter by the column.